# Why is my Saved State Overwritten on Refresh in this Simple React Example?

Tags: reactjs

I am following this [simple tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQAHSlTtcmY) and can't get my saved state to work.

I can see in the comments that other users are having to work around this issue.

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react"
import TodoList from "./TodoList"
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

const LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = 'todosApp.todos'

function App() {
    const [todos, setTodos] = useState([])
    const todoNameRef = useRef()

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(`useEffect[]`)
        const storedTodos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY));
        if (storedTodos) {
            console.log(`set todos to: ${JSON.stringify(storedTodos)}`)
            setTodos(storedTodos)
            // can't print here - value is set asynchronously
            // console.log(`loaded todos: ${JSON.stringify(todos)}`)
        }
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(`useEffect[todos]: ${JSON.stringify(todos)}`)
        if (todos.length != 0) {
            console.log('save')
            localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(todos))
        }
    }, [todos])

    function toggleTodo(id) {
        const newTodos = [...todos]
        const todo = newTodos.find(todo => todo.id === id)
        console.log(`toggleTodo: ${todo.name}`)
        todo.complete = !todo.complete
        setTodos(newTodos)
    }

    function handleAddTodo(e) {
        const name = todoNameRef.current.value
        console.log(`handleAddTodo: ${name}`)
        // setTodos(todos.concat({completed: false, name: todoNameRef.current.value}))
        if (name === '') {
            return
        }
        setTodos([...todos, { id:uuidv4(), name:name, complete:false }])
    }

    return (
      <div>
          <TodoList todos={todos} handleCheckboxChanged={toggleTodo}/>
          <input ref={todoNameRef} type="text" />
          <button onClick={handleAddTodo}>Add Todo</button>
          <button>Clear Completed</button>
          <div>0 left to do</div>
      </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Here's the output:

```
useEffect[]
App.js:15 set todos to: [{"id":"77fe1e9e-91aa-4a34-9bfb-b1842ea5518d","name":"asfd","complete":false},{"id":"8dabea66-4ed9-4f10-9003-af1b34b4558a","name":"asfd","complete":false},{"id":"6d4e9350-11cd-4ace-8766-485e1f8817ad","name":"asfd","complete":false}]
App.js:23 useEffect[todos]: []
App.js:12 useEffect[]
App.js:15 set todos to: []
App.js:23 useEffect[todos]: []
App.js:23 useEffect[todos]: []
```

So it seems like the state is asynchronously initialised after loading the state for some reason.

Here is my workaround:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`useEffect[todos]: ${JSON.stringify(todos)}`)
    if (todos.length != 0) {
        console.log('save')
        localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(todos))
    }
}, [todos])
```

So I have a workaround, but why is this necessary? I can't wrap my head around how this can be intended React functionality.

Answer (score 1):

```
useEffect(() => {
        console.log(`useEffect[todos]: ${JSON.stringify(todos)}`)
        if (todos.length != 0) {
            console.log('save')
            localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(todos))
        }
}, [todos])
```

`useEffect` is always triggered initially, even though it has dependencies. In your case with the above snippet, it will be triggered twice:

- Initial loading (like `[]` - no dependencies)
- Updated `todos` state

So that's why it set empty data to `localStorage` because of initial loading without empty `todos` (if you don't have the condition `todos.length != 0`)

Your above snippet with the condition `todos.length != 0` is reasonable, but it won't work for delete-all cases.

---

If you don't use any server-side rendering frameworks, you can set a default value for `todos` state

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY))
```

With this change, you can update `useEffect` like below

```
useEffect(() => {
   localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(todos))
}, [todos])
```

---

If you use a server-side rendering framework like NextJS, you can try to update `localStorage` directly on events (`toggleTodo` and `handleAddTodo`) instead of `useEffect`.

```
function App() {
    const [todos, setTodos] = useState([])
    const todoNameRef = useRef()

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(`useEffect[]`)
        const storedTodos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY));
        if (storedTodos) {
            console.log(`set todos to: ${JSON.stringify(storedTodos)}`)
            setTodos(storedTodos)
            // can't print here - value is set asynchronously
            // console.log(`loaded todos: ${JSON.stringify(todos)}`)
        }
    }, [])

    function toggleTodo(id) {
        const newTodos = [...todos]
        const todo = newTodos.find(todo => todo.id === id)
        console.log(`toggleTodo: ${todo.name}`)
        todo.complete = !todo.complete
        setTodos(newTodos)
        localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(newTodos))
    }

    function handleAddTodo(e) {
        const name = todoNameRef.current.value
        console.log(`handleAddTodo: ${name}`)
        // setTodos(todos.concat({completed: false, name: todoNameRef.current.value}))
        if (name === '') {
            return
        }
        const updatedTodos = [...todos, { id:uuidv4(), name:name, complete:false }]
        setTodos(updatedTodos)
        localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(updatedTodos))
    }

    return (
      <div>
          <TodoList todos={todos} handleCheckboxChanged={toggleTodo}/>
          <input ref={todoNameRef} type="text" />
          <button onClick={handleAddTodo}>Add Todo</button>
          <button>Clear Completed</button>
          <div>0 left to do</div>
      </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that helped. I think I understand now what is happening. The useEffect call with the [todos] dependency was queued with the initial loading/no dependies case that you described, and then getting called after my loading effect. So I just changed the order of the 2 useEffect calls and now it seems to work without my workaround. Cheers!